# Apple Maps Hyper Links

Tags: ios, query-string, apple-maps

Apple has a special URL that can be used for hyperlinks to physical locations, triggering the native Maps application to launch and render the specified location:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=SEARCH
```

[According to their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1), the links have attributes for zoom level (`z`) and type (`t`), but it doesn't indicate what types of values these properties must be in.

For example, the links in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/y9Xfy/2/) do not recognize the z attribute.

Is there any documentation, elsewhere, on the values that the Map Links properties can be?

**Update:**

The `t` parameter can be set to `k` for satellite view and `h` for hybrid view.

The `z` parameter appears to be ignored in favor of an automatic zoom detection.

Comment: From what I can tell z is the zoom level as an integer. Looks to be primarily based off google so (1-20)? **EDIT** @Daij-Djan beat me

Comment: Yes, the link you provided is in my question under the phrase "According to their documentation" and it does not specify the formatting of the number.

Comment: Your right @MrSlayer, I have removed it from my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the link format was derived from googleMaps since the ios5- maps were based on google all the way.

assuming that:

- z is the zoom level (1-20)
- t is the map type ("k" satellite, "h" hybrid) ... don't think m p or e are implemented by apple

Comment: Thanks, this shores up the `type` parameter, as values `k` and `h` provide the correct map. However, the zoom level seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

to clarify on the other answer in case someone stumble on this like I have, z is ignored if you don't specify a location.

from [Map Links Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1), which has been updated since :

> z : The zoom level. You can use the z parameter only when you also use the sll parameter; in particular, you can’t use z in combination with the spn or sspn parameters.
>
> sll : The search location. You can specify the sll parameter by itself or in combination with the q parameter. For example, http://maps.apple.com/?sll=50.894967,4.341626&z=10&t=s is a valid query. A comma-separated pair of floating point values that represent latitude and longitude (in that order).